# Microservices communication/deployment

Tags: angularjs, http, soa

I read a couple of posts and presentations on Microservices concept and architecture and REST, and was unable to find answer to a few basic question.

1. If service **A** depends on service **B**, how does sevice **A** knows where to find (host and port) service B? I'm guessing hardcoding isn't very nice.
2. If I have, for example, an AngularJS client which request multiple services deployed, how does the angular app knows how to find those multiple services? Again, hardcoding doesn't sound right.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS has [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) baked in.  Use that to construct your dependencies.

If you wanted to reduce the "hard-coding" further, I suppose you could deploy a "Service Registry," which could maintain all of the dependencies.  You could then call the Service Registry service to get the port numbers and such, and maintain them in one place.  Seems to me like overkill, though.

Comment: But still, if the services I'm requesting are deployed to different hosts and/or different ports, I still need to find them. Is hard-coding host and port really the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "hard coding?" The client has to know about the service somehow. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Java based solution to your problem, however it is a very proven method.  Take a look at Spring Cloud / Netflix OSS.  The Spring Cloud project has a working example on github using AngularJS and the various backend services that make up the Spring Cloud solution.

Specifically the following:

Eureka -> Service Discovery, solves the problem of host and port

Zuul -> HTTP Proxy, solves the problem of finding the current host and port via Eureka integration. Zuul can help with security, CORS etc.

Another possible solution is Zookeeper.  I have no experience with Zookeeper.